# Is there any way to differentiate some nodes returned by a cypher query?

Tags: node.js, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-traversal

I use a Neo4j graph database.
My query finds nodes from starting nodes I know (graph traversal in a certain way), as paramter of the query.

I would like to mark these starting nodes, because my query can return these same nodes many times in another part of the returned graph.

This is a fake dummy query example :

```
MATCH (n0 {name:"john"}), (n1 {name:"doe"})
WITH n0, n1
MATCH p=((P)-[:LINK*1..5]->(n0)-[:LINK]->(n1)->[:LINK*1..5]->(N))
WITH collect(P) + collect(N) + n0 as nodes
RETURN nodes;
```

I would like to have n0 and n1 with something special, a new property, because the results can contain other nodes with the same properties/name.

It would be nice to organize the result with arrays, as shown below :

```
[
  [P0, P1, P2, P3],
  [n0, n1],           <--- The 2 starting nodes in the middle !
  [N0, N1, N2, N3]
]
```

Is it possible to mark a part of nodes from result, without updating the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add [labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels) to those nodes, like :StartNode or :Start or similar.

In fact you should be using labels in your graph already, usually when we see queries with no labels present that's a mistake, since that requires an all nodes scan. Please label your nodes according to their role or roles in your graph (like :Person, :Movie, or similar) and ensure you're using appropriate labels in your queries as well.

Labels are also required in order to add [indexes and constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/), which will likely speed up your queries as well.

Nodes can be multi-labeled, so at that point you can add more specific labels to support special cases like what you're requiring here. If you add a :StartNode label on these, then use that label in your queries, then this will use a label scan on all :StartNode labeled nodes, and if these are the only ones with this label then your lookup will be quick.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend restructuring your query to return the minimum required that you need to know (for performance and ease).

In your case, you have 2 distinct Cyphers (here they are in their simplest form)

```
MATCH (n0 {name:"john"})-[:LINK]->(n1 {name:"doe"})-[:LINK]->()
MATCH (P)-[:LINK*1..5]->(n0)
RETURN COLLECT(P);
```

and

```
MATCH ()-[:LINK]->(n0 {name:"john"})-[:LINK]->(n1 {name:"doe"})
MATCH (n1)->[:LINK*1..5]->(N)
RETURN COLLECT(N);
```

Using the same starting MATCH to assert that the `:LINK` exists. They are distinct since the two query have no baring on the other. So the way you combined them will return a cartesian product of these two cyphers.

You can combine these two cyphers using WITH to avoid creating the cartesian product

```
MATCH (n0 {name:"john"})-[:LINK]->(n1 {name:"doe"})
MATCH (P)-[:LINK*1..5]->(n0)
WITH COLLECT(P) as p, n0, n1;
MATCH (n1)->[:LINK*1..5]->(N)
RETURN [p, [n0, n1], COLLECT(N)] as nodes
// Or you could keep the return more normal like this
// RETURN p, n0, n1, COLLECT(N) as n
```

Now, if you REALLY want to mark the nodes like you asked in the question, you could copy all the node's data into a map and mark the map...

```
MATCH (n0 {name:"john"})-[:LINK]->(n1 {name:"doe"})
MATCH (P)-[:LINK*1..5]->(n0)
WITH COLLECT({labels:LABELS(P), properties:PROPERTIES(P), id:ID(P), mark:"P"}) as p, n0, n1;
MATCH (n1)->[:LINK*1..5]->(N)
RETURN [p, [n0, n1], COLLECT({labels:LABELS(N), properties:PROPERTIES(N), id:ID(N), mark:"N"})] as nodes
```

But when you end up copying your entire data-set with minor insignificant changes, that is usually a hint that you are making things more complicated than they need to be. Also, the "mark" is completely redundant in this case as the everything is separated (marked) by column already.

Comment: The question's query has 2 constraints: `n0` must have an incoming `LINK` AND `n1` must have an outgoing `LINK`. The two queries suggested do not enforce both constraints at the same time.

Comment: @cybersam That constraint is enforced by the second match. If it fails, their will be 0 rows left before COLLECT has a chance to do it's thing. Technically, they do interact in that one side can annihilate the other if their is no match. So the combined form is technically slightly more correct. I'll add the missing side of the match anyways though so that they are all correct.